# execute code during iPhone app installation?

Tags: iphone, installation

Is it possible to have code that executes during the iPhone app installation process - i.e. when it is installed from the app store?  I would like to run a method which executes at install time vs when the app first loads.

Comment: What do you want to do at install time that you can't do during the apps first launch?

Comment: @middaparka maybe know if the app was downloaded from a link of another app. You would be able to know it right away; many people doesn't open apps immediately after download.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible - the entire installation process is handled by Apple applications. At no point is your app (or any bundled code) executed during the install.

Comment: You might add a "first launch" check - check for a file in your app's data store: if it's there, you've done your init; if not, you haven't. Do it and then create the file. Bonus: you can store anything that the first run creates/initializes/etc. in that file.

Comment: Thanks Joe...I have this working but given the init can take 5-10 seconds I would rather this was tacked on to the install time verses when the app is first launched.

Comment: If time is a problem for you, consider adding a "first run" screen that displays while your initialization takes place. You can add a spinner or progress bar as necessary.