# Execute sqlite query during mobile app installation in xamarin.forms

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, offline-mode, app-update

Hi I am working on a usecase for my Xamarin.forms app. The usecase is to execute some sqlite queries during app installation to get any database changes information in new app version.

Currently when I launch my app after upgrade to a newer version, I call my api to get the database changes in new version. For e.g. if any existing table is been updated, then I get the information during app launch and accordingly I reset those database tables. Below is my code that executes and gets this information:

```
    public async Task CheckVersionUpdateDevice()
    {
        try
        {
            AppVersion _appVersion = new AppVersion();
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM AppVersion";
            var existingAppVersion = await sqlLiteDatabase.GetItemsAsync<AppVersion>(strSQL);
            Version _currentVersion = Version.Parse(existingAppVersion[0].versionNumber);
            Version _newVersion = AppInfo.Version;

            int comparisonResult = _newVersion.CompareTo(_currentVersion);

            if (comparisonResult > 0)
            {
                var result = _deviceService.GetVersionChangeData(existingAppVersion[0].versionNumber); // #1 Get database changes in new version

                if (result != null && result[0].ChangeList != null && result[0].ChangeList.Count > 0)
                {
                    UpdateTablesAndFiles(result[0].ChangeList); // #2 Reset all the tables.
                }
            }

            _appVersion.versionNumber = _newVersion.ToString();
            await sqlLiteDatabase.InsertOrReplaceAsync<AppVersion>(_appVersion, false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await App.HandleException(ex);
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine, but recently I encountered an issue where user upgraded the app but launched the app in offline mode. Since the app was launched in offline mode, my api at #1 returned with an exception about internet connection. Due to that the updated database information was not received and my upgraded app code that needed that information subsequently failed.

I checked other SO posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565878/execute-code-during-iphone-app-installation) but couldn't find a viable solution so wondering if anyone has any suggestions to like perform some sort of action during app installation to get those latest database changes. Since the app installation will always happen when internet is on.

Any suggestions or thoughts are welcome!

Comment: if its unable to update on startup for any reason, block them from using the app and display an error until they are able connect/update.  OR, build the db change info into the new version instead of getting it from the sever.

Comment: @Jason, thanks for your suggestion. That was my first thought as well, but was wondering if there are other ways to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Xamarin.Essentials: Connectivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?tabs=ios) to check the network first and then decide whether to get database changes or show an alert to tell user need to connect to the Internet:

```
    var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;

    if (current == NetworkAccess.Internet)
    {
        //internet is available
        CheckVersionUpdateDevice();
    }
    else
    {
        //show alert to user
    }
```